# when creating a phar from tar.gz file says its corrupt when it is not

Tags: php, phar

I am creating a phar from a tar.gz file downloaded from a gitlab repo :

```
$tar = new PharData('qa-master-75d95ae0ea324ccb8a9580c37e88ab98f065a3c3.tar.gz');
```

This throws an exception

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'phar error: "/root/tools/testApp/build/qa-master-75d95ae0ea324ccb8a9580c37e88ab98f065a3c3.tar.gz" is a corrupted tar file (checksum mismatch of file "52 comment=75d95ae0ea324ccb8a9580c37e88ab98f065a3c3
```

Yet I can open the tar file using WinRar (for example)

Has anyone else encountered this and if so is there a work around?

Thanks for your time

Comment: `.tar.gz` is a gzipped, tar file. Try un-gzipping the file and using the resulting tar file?

Comment: Same result - corrupted tar file

Comment: Well, PHP isn't lying to you, so something is wrong or unexpected with the file. From the information provided, there's not much we can do.

Comment: I unpacked and repacked the offending archive from the command line and PHP was able to open it. So I guess that gitlab is creating the archive incorrectly